# Unexpected End of JSON Input - Syntax Error With Login System

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, session

I'm using trying to create a login system. However, I am getting unexpected end of JSON input, and am unsure why since it works on another page I'm using.
It's saying unexpected end of JSON input on line 12 of the JS.

The JS I'm using is:

```
$('#formUserLogin').submit(function(event){ // If data is submitted from the form called formUserLogin
    formData = $('#formUserLogin').serialize(); // Serialize data

    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", // Defines type for ajax function
        url: "policeLoginDAO.php", // URL to send data to
        data: formData+"&phpFunction=login", // Data to send + PHP function to use it with
        datatype: 'json', // Datatype to send
        success: function(msg){
            dataJson = JSON.parse(msg);
            if(dataJson['result']=='false') { // If result is false do this:
                $("divMessage").html("Wrong username or password"); // Display message in divMessage div in html page
            } else { // Else if it's correct, do this:
                window.location="../policeHome.php"; // Open page, policeHome.php and set the value of badgeno to the stored badgeno in session storage
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The PHP I'm using is:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['phpFunction'])) {
    if($_POST['phpFunction'] == 'login') {
        login();
    }
}

function login() {

    session_start(); // Starts the session for the user
    include "../../config.php"; // Includes the config file to connect the the database
    $uName = strip_tags($_POST['userName']); // Strips the tags for the username
    $pWord = strip_tags($_POST['password']); // Strips the tags for the password
    $userID = $_SESSION['uName']; // Sets the username to the session
    $uName1 = strip_tags(mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $uName)); // Strips the tags and escapes the string for the username
    $pWord1 = strip_tags(mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $pWord)); // Strips the tags and escapes the string for the password


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_police` WHERE Username='".$uName1."' "; // Selects all data from the tbl_user where email is equal to the user input
    $result = $connection->query($sql); // Result is equal to the queries outcome
    $pass = $row['Password']; // Gets the password
    if ($result->num_rows === 1) { // If the result is identical to 1
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); // Fetch result
        if (password_verify($pWord1, $row['Password'])) { // Verify the password against the users input by using the password_verify function. If it's correct... Do this:

            echo json_encode($row);
            $_SESSION['uName'] = $uName;

        }else{ // If the password is not correct... Do this:
            echo("Hello");

        }
        mysqli_close($connection); // Close the connection to the database
    }
}
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: datatype: 'json' <= ignoring that it should be `dataType`, does not specify what the content type is.  It specifies what the **response** type is.  To specify the content type, hey hey, use the `contentType` property.  Also, if you *do* use the `dataType: 'json'`, then your success does not need to parse the response message.  It will already be parsed by jQuery  https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: So where abouts may the error be?

Comment: You should echo JSON in both the success and failure cases of login authentication.

Comment: @RiggsFolly `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);`

Comment: Side note: I'm not an ajax/jquery guy, but pretty sure that `$("divMessage")` is missing either a `.` or a `#` for it.

Comment: Sorry @Barmar THIS LINE `$pass = $row['Password']; // Gets the password` should be causing an ERRROR. Confused me for a second as to whether you were fetching the result

Comment: I also think that you're most likely outputting before header. Enable error reporting.

Comment: If you are sending JSON back to JS then you should not do this `dataJson = JSON.parse(msg);` as its already JSON

Comment: This code works on another page I'm using, absolutely perfectly... It's just now that I've changed it for a new table for a different group of users, it's throwing this error

Comment: @RiggsFolly True, I didn't see that. But it never uses the `$pass` variable.

Comment: @Barmar Yes I realised that after I posted my slightly embarasing comment :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly And I realized what you were referring to when I was converting the code into my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your PHP script is not returning JSON when the login fails. The JavaScript code expect it to return JSON with a `result` property equal to the string `false`. But the script returns nothing if the username isn't found, and returns `Hello` if the username is found but the password is wrong.

In the code below I initialize an array with a `false` result. If authentication succeeds I change that to `true` and merge in the data from the row. Either way, it echoes the JSON at the end.

I've also converted the code to use a prepared statement to prevent SQL injection.

```
<?php
function login() {

    session_start(); // Starts the session for the user
    include "../../config.php"; // Includes the config file to connect the the database
    $uName = $_POST['userName'];
    $pWord = $_POST['password'];

    $json_array = ['result' => 'false'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_police` WHERE Username= ? "; // Selects all data from the tbl_user where email is equal to the user input
    $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $uName);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if ($result->num_rows === 1) { // If the result is identical to 1
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); // Fetch result
        if (password_verify($pWord, $row['Password'])) { // Verify the password against the users input by using the password_verify function. If it's correct... Do this:
            $json_array['result'] = 'true';
            $json_array = array_merge($json_array, $row);
            $_SESSION['uName'] = $uName;
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($connection); // Close the connection to the database
    echo json_encode($json_array);
}
```

In the jQuery, you should either use

`dataType: 'json'` or `dataJson = JSON.parse(msg)`, but not both. Your code will work as is because you mistyped `dataType:` (JS is case sensitive).

Comment: That code gives no error at all but doesn't log the user in for some reason

Comment: Do you see the JSON being returned in the Network tab?

Comment: @Barmar Look out for this line `dataJson = JSON.parse(msg);` in the success method of OP's Javascript !!

Comment: No, I don't. I really don't know why my code didn't work though because, it works on another page which is why I'm so confused

Comment: If you're not getting any response, check your PHP error log.

Comment: Variable *cough* scope.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner What variable scope? It includes `config.php` inside the function, so the `$connection` variable is local.

Comment: The `login()` function.

Comment: I still don't know what you're referring to. Which variable is not in scope?

Comment: Possible Hiccup :) `$pWord ` !== `$pWord1` but the OP really should be able to spot that for themselves

Comment: Right, I missed that when I was getting rid of all his input sanitizing.

Comment: Dare I suggest you add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` for the OP

Comment: Oh, my mistake then (variable scope). I stand corrected. @Barmar